# How to acces to a property of an event's target in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following element:

```
<h1 msgId = "someId"> Some text </h1>
```

and in a code.js the following function:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    target = e.target;
}, false);
```

I need to obtain the string "someId" in msgId property.
Something like target.msgId

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    id = e.target.msgId;
}, false);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: try with `data-attribute`

Comment: Mozilla has this great place on the web you should visit every now and then.

Comment: @AatifBandey Is that an attribute of e.target ? `e.target.data-attribute` does not work

Comment: ```<h1 data-msg-id = "someId"> Some text </h1>``` ```id = e.target.dataset.msgId```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msgId` is an *attribute* on that element, so you'd use `getAttribute`:

```
console.log(e.target.getAttribute("msgId"));
```

Live Example:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute("msgId"));
}, false);
```

```html
<h1 msgId = "someId"> Some text </h1>
```

**However**, if you're going to use your own attributes, use a `data-` prefix; see [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Element.getAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the value of `msgId` attribute.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    target = e.target.getAttribute("msgId");
    console.log(target);
}, false);
```

```html
<h1 msgId = "someId"> Some text </h1>
```

I would still suggest you to use `data-msgId` as `msgId` will not be a valid HTML5 attribute.

Answer (score -1):

This should work
`e.target.getAttribute("msgId");`

But I would suggest use `data-attribute` since it will be valid HTML5 attribute